# Error in saving CKEDITOR content

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application am allowing the user to create PDF file. Have used CKEDITOR in my application.

```
function create_PDF(box) {
        var filename = $("#filename").val();
        if (filename == "") {
            alert("Enter filename");
            return false;
        }
        var content = CKEDITOR.instances["message"].getData();
        if (content == "") {
            alert("Enter Content in The Editor");
            return false;
        }
        content = content.trim();
        dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
        dhtmlx.message("Saving file...");
        $.post("/FileUpload/CreateNewPDFile",
    {
        filename: '' + filename + '', content: '' + content + ''
    }, function (data) {

        alert("PDF File created succesfully");
        CKEDITOR.instances["message"].setData("");
    });
    }
```

CreateNewPDFFile controller code is:

```
  public ActionResult CreateNewPDFile(FormCollection data)
    {
        var filename = data["filename"];
        var htmlContent = data["content"];
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath(_createdPDF + filename + ".pdf");
        htmlContent = htmlContent.Trim();
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sFilePath))
        {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
            doc.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
            doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Width, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Height));
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new System.IO.FileStream(sFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            iTextSharp.text.Font fnt = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 14);
            doc.Open();
            PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell pdfCell = null;
            pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(htmlContent)));
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell);
            doc.Add(pdfTab);
            doc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(doc);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

PDF file gets created successfully but the displays HTML content in it
for example: If i have inserted radio buttons in the file than in newly created file it displays

```
<input name="age" type="radio"
```

value="15-20" />

and not the radio buttons.
How can I avoid html content ?

Comment: PDF does not support HTML radio button. You actually want a printscreen instead?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor  I want to allow the user to add form fields at cursor position in PDF. How can i do it?

Comment: PDF is not as dynamic as HTML. You can't `allow the user to add form fields at cursor position in PDF`

Comment: @Shivan Raptor  how can I allow the user to add form fields in the new pdf file.

Comment: Use Acrobat or some similar software (but not asp.net) to make it : http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/create-fillable-pdf-forms-acrobat.html

Comment: @Shivan Raptor I want to create something like this http://www.pdfamigo.com/edit that will allow the user to add form fields

Comment: There is Acrobat and PDF Library API. You can have a look: http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_API_Reference/index.html?class-summary.html&all-classes.html&package-list.html ( but it seems can't fulfill your needs )